# using consul-template with full Windows paths

Tags: windows, consul, hashicorp, consul-template

I'm having trouble invoking `consul-template` on Windows.  For example, I would like to run the command

```
consul-template -in "c:\in.tpl:c:\out.tpl"
```

Obviously, the colons are a problem, and I can't seem to find documentation about how to escape them.  I expect the backslashes might also cause issues.  Any ideas?

I've Googled and been unable to find a working example that uses complete Windows paths.